# How to correctly use google analytics measurement protocol?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm learning to use google analytics for apps. For test purpose i have created a new google account, enabled analytics for apps and issued following command from terminal to test is it working:

```
curl "http://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&tid=UA-12345678-1&cid=123&an=myapp&t=event&ec=action&ea=click"
```

Unfortunately, this request don't affect any numbers i see on analytics page - it's all zeroes. Any request to google analytics results in "200 OK" and 1x1 pixel gif image, so i can't figure out the problem: is the request incorrect, or i need to somehow preconfigure google analytics, or it have days delay before data is displayed etc.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It takes up to 24 hours before data is displayed in the standard reports.  Have you checked the real-time reports?

Comment: Yes, it's here! Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like your issue was solved. Some pointers for other people coming to this page:

- Look in realtime reports.
- Try to send pageview or screenview instead of event. They show up in more places.
- The cid should be a [UUID v4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_.28random.29).

Comment: Still couldn't see anything in my real time. 
One question does the UUID v4 needs to be generated each time of the request?

Comment: nope. The uuid should stay the same for a given user+device combination. If you change it with every request, you'll see a lot of unique users even though they are repeat visitors.

Comment: Can you guide me how to get the user+device UUID combination?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by get uuid. UUID v4 is a anonymous, random id that can be generated by following instructions here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UUID#Version_4_.28random.29. You need to generate the id from whichever language you are using.

Comment: Ok. I get it. I tried all the way. I followed all the instructions as per the Google Analytics Measurement Protocol. But all the time I get a GIF 89. I don't see any activity in my Analytics Real Time console.

Comment: @Debopam did you resolved your issues? i have the same situation here, no realtime stats...

Answer (score 6):

For debuging your requests you can use this URL:

**/debug/collect**

instead of

**/collect**

In response body you will see details.