# Google Analytics Measurement Protocol not working

Tags: cordova, google-analytics, node-webkit

I want to track an application that runs in different environments:

- phonegap build
- node-webkit app
- website

In order to use one tracking mechanism for all I thought it would be a good idea to use  the  ["Measurement Protocol"](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide)

I set up a new tracking property (type Website) and performed multiple requests to the `www.google-analytics.com/collect` site as described in their devguide. I always get the `Status 200 (OK)` from my POST request, but unfortunately I can´t see any tracking information coming in to my GA account.

Here is what the request looks like (Build with Postman plugin for Chrome):

```
POST /collect?v=1&tid=UA-29xxxxxx-2&cid=35009a79-1a05-49d7-b876-2b884d0f825b&t=pageview&dh=mysite.com&dp=%2Fhome&dt=Homepage&an=myapp HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google-analytics.com
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

Basically I´m sending these parameters:

```
v=1
&tid=UA-29xxxxxx-2
&cid=35009a79-1a05-49d7-b876-2b884d0f825b
&t=pageview
&dh=mysite.com
&dp=%2Fhome
&dt=Homepage
&an=myapp
```

I also tried to create a "Mobile Application" in Google Analytics and use that tracking id instead. Same result here - no tracking information in Google Analytics.

Does anyone know, how to perform this tracking requests successfully or if there is a debug-option so that I can at least see, why the tracking call is not saved? Thanks!

Comment: How long did you wait after creating these new Web Properties?  It takes 24 - 48 hours before they are going to start showing data.

Comment: I created them 4h ago or so. Are the real-time-reports not updated immediately?

Comment: It takes 48 - 72 hours before Google will start recording data on a new web property you will need to wait.

Comment: No @DaImTo, the Real Time Data.. is in Real Time. You don't need to wait to see the data on real time dashboard.

Comment: take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22894416/how-to-correctly-use-google-analytics-measurement-protocol)

Comment: I am having the exact same issue. Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: @Buzzy try the `/debug/collect` endpoint specified here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/validating-hits to get some feedback from GA.

Answer (score 21):

Had the same problem: whatever I POSTed, it did not show up in GA. Debug API successfully validated my hits. Finally, I found out what was missing: you must send a user agent string (parameter ua), too.

Comment: You, sir, saved my day with this simple and valuable piece of information.

Comment: Thanks a lot, bro. Your comment is amazing. You help me!

Answer (score 3):

Cross reference to other given solutions:
[How to correctly use google analytics measurement protocol?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22894416/how-to-correctly-use-google-analytics-measurement-protocol)

Takeaway:

- use the `/debug/collect` endpoint
- Check the GA live report after a try with `/collect`
- Check you ua and cid parameters
- Use proxying that browser extensions don't fish away your requests

My request now looks like: https://strongstaff.eu/statistics?v=1&tid=UA-XXX&cid=35009a79-1a05-49d7-b876-2b884d0f825b&t=pageview&dp=/&dt=Homepage&an=myapp%20HTTP/1.1&ua=Mmyapp%20HTTP/1.1

which proxy_pass'es to: 
`proxy_pass https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?$args;`

Comment: /debug/collect works